# error on placeholder (?,?)

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to pass string array and int array to database. Code I am trying is below, but this always shows the error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?)' at line 1

```
Connection connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase", "java", "password");
CompareAndCount compareAndCount = new CompareAndCount();
ReadWord bagOfWords = new ReadWord();
String[] listOfWords = bagOfWords.openFile();
int[] count =compareAndCount.compareWords();
for (int i = 0; i < listOfWords.length; i++) {
    String query = "INSERT INTO angry(tagwords,termfrequency) VALUES(?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pStmnt = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(query);
    pStmnt.setString(1, listOfWords[i]);
    pStmnt.setLong(2, count[i]);
    pStmnt.executeUpdate(query);
}
connection.close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
pStmnt.executeUpdate(query);
```

by

```
pStmnt.executeUpdate();
```

And prepare the statement once, before the loop, instead of re-preparing it again and again at each iteration.